# Remote Partition: Why Steps not run in parallel?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using the **Spring Batch remote partitioning**. My steps are not running in parallel. Instead they run sequentially I mean the partitioned steps run sequentially. **What is the root cause of the issue?**

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING AT US?

Comment: I am not shouting. I really need this detail/explaination. sorry if misunderstood

Comment: You are STILL SHOUTING. Look at the main page of questions; how many do you see that are TYPED IN ALL CAPS? (The answer: None, because like everywhere else on the internet typing in ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING, and we don't SHOUT at each other here.) You're not only SHOUTING, but are **SHOUTING LOUDLY** by making it bold. Please [edit] your question accordingly. You should also take the [tour] and read through the [help] pages, particularly [ask].

Comment: Sorry Ken on this. I changed

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to Spring Batch, but I had similar problem when I first tried writing my own partitioned step.

In my case, the problem was my taskExecutor (which wasn't asynchronous).
I added a @Bean that initialized an asynTaskExecutor and chained that to my partition step. Eureka, it worked.

Here is an example:

```
private Step partitionStep() throws SQLException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("example_partitionstep")
            .partitioner(step.getName(), columnRangePartitioner(partitionColumn, tableName))
            .partitionHandler(taskExecutorPartitionHandler(step))
            .build();
}
```

For the step:

```
private Step step() throws SQLException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("example_step")
            .<>chunk(1000)
            .reader(cursorItemReader(0L, 0L))
            .processor(compositeItemProcessor())
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .build();
}
```

And for the TaskExecutor:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();

    taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(6);

    return taskExecutor;
}
```